# Angular multiple router outlets without auxiliary routes

Tags: angular, router-outlet

Is there any way we can use mulitple `<router-outlet>` entries on an angular component, and load different components/modules, based on route?

I have managed to do this using the [Outlet Context](https://angular.io/api/router/OutletContext), and [Template Variable references](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#template-variable-references), but this introduces a lot of complexity for handling Auxiliary Routes.

My main goal is to load a different header component/module (preferable lazy loaded) based on which route the user is, in the same way the primary `<router-outlet>` works.

The following example does not work. Is there any other way to achieve this?

`app.component.html`

```html
<div class="application-wrapper">
  <header>
    <router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
  </header>
  
  <main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>

  <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

`app-routing.module.ts`

```js
//...
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'intro'},
  {
    path: 'intro',
    component: IntroComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'intro',
    component: HeaderOneComponent,
    outlet: 'header'
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: HeaderTwoComponent,
    outlet: 'header'
  },
];
//...
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and I think I figured it out. You would do:

```js
//...
const routes: Routes = [
  //...
  {
    path: 'intro',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: IntroComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: HeaderOneComponent,
        outlet: 'header'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: HeaderTwoComponent,
        outlet: 'header'
      }
    ]
  }
];
//...
```